# Can I check status of Metadata Deploy using the jobId returned by enqueueDeployment() from Apex?

Tags: apex, metadata-api, metadata

`Metadata.operations.enqueueDeployment()` returns a jobId.  Is it possible to use this jobId to get the status of the deploy?  The callback doesn't help me as I'm working in LWC context; The LWC asks the Apex Controller to deploy a Custom MDT record, and I'd like the LWC to periodically ask the Apex Controller if the deploy has completed.  I'd image I could call the `checkDeployStatus()` method of the Metadata API directly, but up to this point I've been able to use plain Apex, without the need for callouts.  I don't see a ToolingAPI object for DeployRequest to query.  Is this possible?

Comment: have you looked at andyinthecloud CustomMetadataApi repo: https://andyinthecloud.com/2017/08/29/introducing-custom-metadata-services/

Comment: On top of the referenced answer, your callback class can write a record to wherever (custom object/etc) and then poll that from your LWC.